# Performance tuning a piece of C# / SQL code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code which works so far but I would like to know if it can be improved in any way, either for speed or to prevent any potential other issues. The log data structure can have hundreds of thousands of items.

```
public void Save()
{
    foreach (var v in _log_data)
    {
        string query = @"INSERT INTO TransactionLog ( DataType, UserName, UserEmail, UserCountry, [DateTime])
                         VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4})";
        _ctx.ExecuteCommand(query,  v.DataType, v.UserName, v.UserName, v.UserCountry,  v.DateTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use **parametrized** queries instead of stringing together your SQL statements - this is **(a)** beneficial against SQL injection attacks (the #1 vulnerability on the 'Net), and **(b)** beneficial for overall system performance since execution plans can be reused and don't have to be figured out over and over again.

Comment: @marc_s - That **is** a parameterized query (assuming this is Entity Framework).

Comment: This was linq to sql.  Is sql injection still an issue while using linq to sql data context?

Comment: Does anyone know how InsertAllOnSubmit compares with the SqlBulkCopy described below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SqlBulkcopy :

```
        var sbCopy = new SqlBulkCopy("myConnectionString")
        {
            DestinationTableName = tableName,
            BatchSize = 100000
        };

        sbCopy.WriteToServer(_log_data.AsDataReader());
```

The AsDataReader() method is from the EntityDataReader Extensions

Comment: Great and thank you. Could you brefly explain how this will make the code any faster?

Comment: bulkCopy bypass SQLServer controls and is way faster than usual insert into

Comment: Is there any standard way of implementing AsDataReader on my Custum collection _log_data?

Comment: you can look there :http://csharplight.blogspot.fr/2012/03/ienumerable-asdatareader-sqlbulkcopy.html

Comment: Thanks. It looks like i need EF. Any idea if i actually need to create a mapping or just need to install EF on my machine to have access to the assemblies?